# What is an efficient way to compute the Dice coefficient between 900,000 strings?

Tags: multithreading, string, algorithm

I have a corpus of 900,000 strings.  They vary in length, but have an average character count of about 4,500.  I need to find the most efficient way of computing the [Dice coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice_coefficient) of every string as it relates to every other string.  Unfortunately, this results in the Dice coefficient algorithm being used some 810,000,000,000 times.

What is the best way to structure this program for increased efficiency?  Obviously, I can prevent computing the Dice of sections A and B, and then B and A--but this only halves the work required.  Should I consider taking some shortcuts or creating some sort of binary tree?

I'm using the following implementation of the Dice coefficient algorithm in Java:

```
public static double diceCoefficient(String s1, String s2) {
    Set<String> nx = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> ny = new HashSet<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length() - 1; i++) {
        char x1 = s1.charAt(i);
        char x2 = s1.charAt(i + 1);
        String tmp = "" + x1 + x2;
        nx.add(tmp);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < s2.length() - 1; j++) {
        char y1 = s2.charAt(j);
        char y2 = s2.charAt(j + 1);
        String tmp = "" + y1 + y2;
        ny.add(tmp);
    }

    Set<String> intersection = new HashSet<String>(nx);
    intersection.retainAll(ny);
    double totcombigrams = intersection.size();

    return (2 * totcombigrams) / (nx.size() + ny.size());
}
```

My ultimate goal is to output an ID for every section that has a Dice coefficient of greater than 0.9 with another section.

Thanks for any advice that you can provide!

Comment: Link-to/explanation-of the Dice coefficient would be good for posterity.

Comment: What output do you want? Do you want N items with the highest coefficient?

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I have edited my original post to include both details.

Comment: What's the allowed character range?

Comment: If you want to find similar strings/documents, I am pretty sure you'll be able to find similar items much faster than O(n^2) by doing something clever like sim hashing.

Comment: It's a shame that Dice doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality. Is it not possible to use a distance metric that does? It would certainly reduce processing time. Of course if you only want an approximate result, you can pretend that it is real distance.

Comment: This paper presents a method that finds 90% of the top 50 nearest neighbors for each record using Jacard (similar to Dice) for a 900k sized data set of bibliography records by examining less than 3% of the pairs. http://www.www2011india.com/proceeding/proceedings/p577.pdf

Comment: The allowed character range is all alphanumeric characters and the space.  I'm not looking to cluster--just to locate near duplicate strings.  I'm also not set on the Dice coefficient, and am open to suggestions regarding alternatives.

Comment: Using a HashSet in the diceCoefficient method seems overkill to me. You can afford an array of booleans indexed by every digrams (1369 of them in your case). Two such arrays will help you count the distinct digrams as well as the digrams common to two strings, in a much more efficient way.

Comment: Given the length of your strings, one may fear that the Dice coefficient on bigrams won't be very discriminant here. I'd recommend using higher order n-grams, possibly after a first filtering on bigram Dice. String edit distance would be fine, but way too costly here.

Answer (score 3):

Make a single pass over all the Strings, and build up a HashMap which maps each bigram to a set of the indexes of the Strings which contain that bigram. (Currently you are building the bigram set 900,000 times, redundantly, for each String.)

Then make a pass over all the sets, and build a HashMap of [index,index] pairs to common-bigram counts. (The latter Map should not contain redundant pairs of keys, like [1,2] and [2,1]  -- just store one or the other.)

Both of these steps can easily be parallelized. If you need some sample code, please let me know.

**NOTE** one thing, though: from the 26 letters of the English alphabet, a total of 26x26 = 676 bigrams can be formed. Many of these will never or almost never be found, because they don't conform to the rules of English spelling. Since you are building up *sets* of bigrams for each String, and the Strings are so long, you will probably find almost the same bigrams in each String. If you were to build up *lists* of bigrams for each String (in other words, if the *frequency* of each bigram counted), it's more likely that you would actually be able to measure the degree of similarity between Strings, but then the calculation of Dice's coefficient as given in the Wikipedia article wouldn't work; you'd have to find a new formula.

I suggest you continue researching algorithms for determining similarity between Strings, try implementing a few of them, and run them on a smaller set of Strings to see how well they work.

Answer (score 0):

You should come up with some kind of inequality like: D(X1,X2) > 1-p, D(X1,X3) < 1-q and p D(X2,X3) < 1-q+p . Or something like that. Now, if 1-q+p < 0.9, then probably you don't have to evaluate D(X2,X3).

PS: I am not sure about this exact inequality, but I have a gut feeling that this might be right (but I do not have enough time to actually do the derivations now). Look for some of the inequalities with other similarity measures and see if any of them are valid for Dice co-efficient.

=== Also ===

If there are a elements in set A, and if your threshold is r (=0.9), then set B should have number of elements b should be such that: r*a/(2-r) <= b <= (2-r)*a/r . This should eliminate need for lots of comparisons IMHO. You can probably sort the strings according to length and use the window describe above to limit comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer first:  This will *not* reduce the number of comparisons you'll have to make.  But this should make a Dice comparison faster.

1)  Don't build your HashSets every time you do a diceCoefficient() call!  It should speed things up considerably if you just do it once for each string and keep the result around.

2)  Since you only care about if a particular bigram is *present* in the string, you could get away with a BitSet with a bit for each possible bigram, rather than a full HashMap.  Coefficient calculation would then be simplified to ANDing two bit sets and counting the number of set bits in the result.

3)  Or, if you have a huge number of possible bigrams (Unicode, perhaps?) - or monotonous strings with only a handful of bigrams each - a sorted Array of bigrams might provide faster, more space-efficent comparisons.

Answer (score -1):

Is their charset limited somehow? If it is, you can compute character counts by their code in each string and compare these numbers. After such pre-computation (it will occupy 2*900K*S bytes of memory [if we assume no character is found more then 65K time in the same string], where S is different character count). Then computing the coefficent would take O(S) time. Sure, this would be helpful if S<4500.

Comment: The charset is limited to all alphanumeric characters and the space.  I'm a little unclear on how to implement your method.

Comment: It's similar to what Xavier Holt said in item 3: you compute the count of each bigram (I made a mistake and thought you need letters only, but it does not change the nature of the algorithm) in each string, store it to an array, then you compare only these bigram count numbers. The drawback is that it takes up a lot of space.